# What is symmetry of p- and d-orbitals in ${D_{3h}}$?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, symmetry

To identify IR and Raman active, symmetry of p- and d-orbitals are used.

If we start since making ${D_{3h}}$ character table, how to match between symmetry of p- and d-orbitals and Mulliken symbol? because when I tried to find out, symmetry after doing symmetry operation isn't similar with any symmetry (Mulliken symbols).

For example, considering ${AsCl_5}$
[image: symmetry operation of p_x of AsCl5]

compared with ${D_{3h}}$ character table
[image: D3h character table]

Comment: The p orbitals can be considered to be unit vectors along their respective axes. Thus they transform as displacements in $x,\; y$ and $z$, hence transform as $E'$ for $x$ and $y$ and $A_2''$ for $z$.